# Replacing blank cells with condition from the same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have this data frame where all variables are factors:

```
V1            V2
Standard     Tom
             Matt
             John
Community    Steve
             Randy
Age          Robert
Engine       Arthur
Support      Amanda
             Cindy
             Bill
Team         Becky
             Sandra
             Kent
```

What I would like to do is to replace the missing values with the value above the same column. Maybe a function to fill the blanks from the first column based upon the same values from the same column.

I guess it's better to show an example:

```
V1            V2
Standard     Tom
Standard     Matt
Standard     John
Community    Steve
Community    Randy
Age          Robert
Engine       Arthur
Support      Amanda
Support      Cindy
Support      Bill
Team         Becky
Team         Sandra
Team         Kent
```

This is only a part of the data.frame because it has more than 1,000 rows and basically the same pattern is presented in the first column.

Is there a way to make it reproducible?

Comment: See `zoo::na.locf()`

Comment: First assign `NA` to `V1` as `df1$V1[ df1$V1 == ""  ] <- NA` then follow solutions on duplicated post.